# Access saved passwords in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a portal running for which I have saved my credentials. 
Now I am developing an extension for same portal in which user needs to be authenticated.
I am trying to fetch saved username ans Passwords for that portal in the extension.
Can anyone tell me how it can be achieved.

Comment: There is no API to access the credentials storage; however, depending on how your portal's authentication works, there may be workarounds. You need to add more details regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access to a list of his password. But if he is on a website, ex: facebook.com and Chrome autofills the login form, then you can access to his data if you added `https://facebook.com` in the extension permissions. Here is a simple [example](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/07/stealing-login-details-with-google.html).

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/1066399/412763)

Comment: ..which is a bad idea, since the extension has no secure storage for those.

Comment: Sure it's a bad idea. But in some cases, it can be useful :)